How to make a fair voting result
I am a staff member of a Geometry Dash project that, in part, ranks the hardest Geometry Dash levels. To do this, we hold a vote, where users rank a level (e.g., if a user votes #34, they think it's the 34th hardest level). So far, the process is imperfect, and we choose between taking the average or the median of the votes. The problem with taking the average is that the outlier votes get too strong of a say. The problem with taking the median is that the outliers get no say (or at least, only get a say as to whether they are to the lower or higher end of the spectrum). And the problem with doing both is that there is no single standard (we are using median or mean based on whether it seems at a glance that there's a lot of outliers). I am trying to change this.
For context as to what kind of explanation I'd understand, I am a graduated math/CS major, but also have only taken a basic "Statistics for Engineers" course.

This is the equation I've come up with (it is not based on any established method, so maybe it'll end up being arbitrary idk, if the method described below isn't tweakable to be ideal, I would greatly appreciate alternative methods). All votes are to be weighted, and then you take the average of that. For each vote x, weight $w$ are determined in the following way:
$$w = (\frac{1}{|x - μ|/σ})^k$$
In this equation, $\frac{|x - μ|}{σ}$ is the number of standard deviations $x$ is from the mean. From there, the weight is inversely proportionate to the standard deviation, so that those that are more outlier-y will be weighted less.
From there, it's raised to the power of $k$, which is calculated to take into account the idea that you want to get something close to the median towards the ends of the spectrum (e.g., if something is obviously the hardest level, but some absurd or troll votes vote weirdly low, you still want it to be ranked #1. On the other hand, when a level is going to be somewhere in mid-range difficulty, you want to start caring about fairness in considering outlier votes in some capacity). With $m$ being the median, $k$ is calculated as $\frac{|100 - m|}{100}$. There are 200 levels being ranked, so if the votes are on the extremes of the spectrum, the $|100-m|$ part will make $k$ large (therefore making it closer to the median). If it is closer to the middle, it will make $k$ small (making the result closer to the mean). Dividing by 100 is an arbitrary choice to determine how much the median or mean is weighed.
Finally, the weighted votes for each raw vote are determined by $w * x$, and the weighted average is calculated by dividing the sum of the weighted votes by the sum of the weights.

Are there better formulas than this? I kinda just made it out of thin air based on what I felt was important to consider. I got some ideas from methods I found online, but honestly I didn't understand most of it, so I'm worried what I have here is subpar.

I realize I already stated a lot, but on top of that, we are also planning to revamp the voting system even more. For reasons I won't get into, we have found voting a single placement is not ideal. Instead, we want to make it so that for each level, users can vote which levels are easier than it, and which levels are harder than it. Users can specific any number of levels that are easier, and any number of levels that are harder.
How would I even start to construct a fair weighted vote for this? Or would I even need to weigh them? I'm not entirely sure how to start conceptualizing a system for this.

How about giving each voter  votes to distribute as they see fit? That could "smooth out" the outliers.

How would giving n votes make it work? In either scenario described, it seems it would either be 1) for voting a ranking, they would vote the same ranking n times or 2) for voting which levels are easier and harder, I don't see how setting a fixed number of votes as opposed to letting people vote for as many levels as possible would help

Check out Winsorizing

Perhaps use a truncated mean score as a compromise between mean and median?

For anyone curious, since I didn't get many responses, I did further research and finally found a solution: the Bradley-Terry model. I used equation 5 of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model#Estimating_the_parameters. I also used this to make an Elo rating for the levels. This is the best method I could find in my opinion. It allows users to send a list of their rankings, we generate comparisons based off of those rankings (for example, a list of "levelA, levelB, levelC" generates comparisons "levelA > levelB", "levelA > levelC", "levelB > levelC", and feed it into the system, allowing for n^2 comparisons with n votes/rankings, and as of right now in beta testing alone, we are generating 400,000 comparisons with 2,500 votes (a lot of those comparisons are comparing super hard levels with super easy levels, but the point still stands that we are getting much richer data than we otherwise would), which will only get better once it's officially released. Additionally, to my understanding Bradley-Terry is a norm for these kind of problems where comparisons are made. Only significant downside is that we have to avoid placing a level before we have enough votes/comparisons to avoid too sparse data. But that has been, for the most part, more than manageable.
More specifically, I think Bradley-Terry is better than scores that have hard cut-offs as to what it considers an outlier and what doesn't. Whether it be weighing outliers differently, assigning outliers different values, or entirely discounting outliers: Bradley-Terry treats the data in a much smoother, less arbitrary manner.
It seems there is a variation of Bradley-Terry that also accounts for the position of a level in people's rankings (like instead of saying "levelA > levelC", it sees that levelA is 2 places above levelC), but the math looks more complicated and there's a lot less documentation on it, so I have opted to not try to use it.
